# How to extract - capital letters and digits in between two words, in a string?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm extracting information from an Image of an Invoice using `PyTesseract` and I need to tag the relevant fields to their values

I've tried using regex to extract content, but this is a new concept and I've been able to extract words that contain capital letters, but not a combination of both letters and digits in between particular words

```
re.findall(r'[A-Z]+', string)
```

Example Sentence - `Hello. I AM IRONMAN even though I would've preferred TO BE BATMAN. 123457678. Superhero FANTASY`.

Expected Result - `I AM IRONMAN I TO BE BATMAN. 123457678`.

Comment: Why is the `I` between *though* and *would've* not matched?

Comment: Oops, did not notice that. It did match

Comment: And how come you don't want `FANTASY` to be matched? Is that the "particular" word you are referring to?

Comment: The information that needs to be tagged is what I've mentioned as the Expected Result. Info beyond 12345678 is not relevant

Comment: Try `" ".join(re.findall(r'\b[A-Z0-9]+(?:\W+[A-Z0-9]+)+\b', string))`. But it will result in `I AM IRONMAN TO BE BATMAN. 123457678`. Either  `I` or `FANTASY` should(not) be there.

Comment: @thegooner did my solution work for you?

Comment: Yes it did help provide a path to the solution I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine a split on the delimiter of interest, *123457678*, and then apply a regex:

```
import re

string = "Hello. I AM IRONMAN even though I would've preferred TO BE BATMAN. 123457678. Superhero FANTASY"
re.findall(r'[A-Z0-9]+\b\.?', ''.join(re.split('(?<=123457678\.).', string)[0]))
# ['I', 'AM', 'IRONMAN', 'I', 'TO', 'BE', 'BATMAN.', '123457678.']
```